# Does any Framework Support User to draw "candle graph" on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, core-plot, graphic

iPhone sdk :Does any Framework Support User to draw "candle graph" in iphone sdk?
[image]

I have tried following framework:

1. MIMChart-Library
2. CorePlot

But it seems not example to show that how to draw Candle Graph......

Or user need to customize by ourself?

Because i am trying to draw candle graph by some framework,

i understand that i has not much Framework support draw candle graph , because it is little bit hard to draw...

Comment: somebody call this is "Candlestick Chart"

Comment: There is an API by Google for websites to draw a Candle stick chart http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/docs/making_charts.html . But writing it in iPhone sdk so that it draws a chart in a UIWebView will be an arduous task. Even I've been trying this and other methods available myself but no luck yet. I even tried to add this module in Core-Plot library but couldn't succeed in drawing it dynamically.

Comment: thx! i think we are having a same problem...

Comment: Now i am trying to customize their framework...Core-Plot

Comment: Do tell me if you succeed, thanks in advance.

Comment: yes, but actually...i am still waiting some hero to give me an answer in here...:P

Answer (score 1):

Core Plot can draw candlestick plots. The Plot Gallery example app includes one.

Comment: thx and i found that the AAPLot example is more like what am i looking for, now i am studying their code how to modify...thx! :]

Answer (score 1):

everyone.

I just found that there has a example code in **CorePlot** named "AAPLot"

It seems like the Candlestick plots we are looking at in Stock Market....

Hope this reference can help you guys. :]